# Custom Minecraft Shader Bugs

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I copied some files from a few shaders, and it works out for the most part, but I sometimes get graphical glitches like this where faces of grass blocks are completely transparent:

[image: Some transparent blocks]

[image: More transparent blocks]

[image: They are transparent, not blue.]

I believe my `gbuffers_terrain.fsh` or `gbuffers_terrain.vsh` is what is causing the problem.

`gbuffers_terrain.fsh`:

```
#version 120
#extension GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod : enable 
/* DRAWBUFFERS:0247 */

/*
RRe36's Shaders, derived from Chocapic13 v4
Place two leading Slashes in front of the following '#define' lines in order to disable an option.
IMPORTANT: Placing Slashes in front of lines like '#define FILTER_LEVEL 15.0' will cause errors!
*/

//-------- Adjustable Variables --------//

    //---- Normal Mapping ----//
        #define NORMAL_MAPPING
            #define NORMAL_MAP_MAX_ANGLE 1.0

    //---- End of Normal Mapping ----//

    //---- Parallax Displacement aka. POM ----//
        //#define POM
            #define POM_MAP_RES 128.0
            #define POM_DEPTH (1.0/20.0)
            const float MAX_OCCLUSION_DISTANCE = 32.0;
            const float MIX_OCCLUSION_DISTANCE = 28.0;
            const int   MAX_OCCLUSION_POINTS   = 12;

    //---- End of Parallax Displacement ----//

    //---- Lightmaps ----//
        #define MIN_LIGHTAMOUNT 0.1     //affect the minecraft lightmap (not torches)
        #define MINELIGHTMAP_EXP 2.0        //affect the minecraft lightmap (not torches)

    //---- End of Lightmaps ----//

//-------- End of Adjustable Variables --------//

/* Here, intervalMult might need to be tweaked per texture pack.  
   The first two numbers determine how many samples are taken per fragment.  They should always be the equal to eachother.
   The third number divided by one of the first two numbers is inversely proportional to the range of the height-map. */
const vec3 intervalMult = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0/POM_DEPTH)/POM_MAP_RES * 1.0; 



const int RGBA16 = 3;
const int RGB16 = 2;
const int RGB8 = 1;
const int gnormalFormat = RGB16;
const int compositeFormat = RGBA16;
const int gaux2Format = RGBA16;
const int gcolorFormat = RGB8;

const int GL_EXP = 2048;
const int GL_LINEAR = 9729;

const float bump_distance = 64.0;           //bump render distance: tiny = 32, short = 64, normal = 128, far = 256
const float pom_distance = 32.0;            //POM render distance: tiny = 32, short = 64, normal = 128, far = 256
const float fademult = 0.1;


varying vec2 lmcoord;
varying vec4 color;
varying float translucent;
varying vec4 vtexcoordam; // .st for add, .pq for mul
varying vec4 vtexcoord;
varying float dist;

varying vec3 tangent;
varying vec3 normal;
varying vec3 binormal;
varying vec3 viewVector;

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler2D normals;
uniform sampler2D specular;
uniform vec3 sunPosition;
uniform vec3 moonPosition;
uniform int fogMode;
uniform int worldTime;
uniform float wetness;
uniform float rainStrength;

float totalspec = 0.0;
float wetx = clamp(wetness, 0.0f, 1.0)/1.0;

const float mincoord = 1.0/4096.0;
const float maxcoord = 1.0-mincoord;

vec2 dcdx = dFdx(vtexcoord.st*vtexcoordam.pq);
vec2 dcdy = dFdy(vtexcoord.st*vtexcoordam.pq);

vec4 readTexture(in vec2 coord){
    return texture2DGradARB(texture,fract(coord)*vtexcoordam.pq+vtexcoordam.st,dcdx,dcdy);
}

vec4 readNormal(in vec2 coord){
    return texture2DGradARB(normals,fract(coord)*vtexcoordam.pq+vtexcoordam.st,dcdx,dcdy);
}

float normalmap_intensity   = NORMAL_MAP_MAX_ANGLE-((NORMAL_MAP_MAX_ANGLE*rainStrength)*0.95);

//////////////////////////////main//////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////main//////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////main//////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////main//////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////main//////////////////////////////

void main() {

vec2 adjustedTexCoord = vtexcoord.st*vtexcoordam.pq+vtexcoordam.st;     

#ifdef POM
    if (dist < MAX_OCCLUSION_DISTANCE) {
    if ( viewVector.z < 0.0 && readNormal(vtexcoord.st).a < 0.99 && readNormal(vtexcoord.st).a > 0.01) 
    {
        vec3 interval = viewVector.xyz * intervalMult;
        vec3 coord = vec3(vtexcoord.st, 1.0);
        for (int loopCount = 0; 
                (loopCount < MAX_OCCLUSION_POINTS) && (readNormal(coord.st).a < coord.p);
                ++loopCount) {
            coord = coord+interval;
        }



        // Don't wrap around top of tall grass/flower
        if (coord.t < mincoord) {
            if (readTexture(vec2(coord.s,mincoord)).a == 0.0) {
                coord.t = mincoord;
                discard;
            }
        }

        adjustedTexCoord = mix(fract(coord.st)*vtexcoordam.pq+vtexcoordam.st , adjustedTexCoord , max(dist-MIX_OCCLUSION_DISTANCE,0.0)/(MAX_OCCLUSION_DISTANCE-MIX_OCCLUSION_DISTANCE));
    }
}
#endif

    vec3 lightVector;   

    vec3 specularity = texture2DGradARB(specular, adjustedTexCoord.st, dcdx, dcdy).rgb;
    float atten = 1.0-(specularity.b)*0.86;

    vec4 frag2 = vec4(normal, 1.0f);

        vec3 bump = texture2DGradARB(normals, adjustedTexCoord.st, dcdx, dcdy).rgb*2.0-1.0;

        float bumpmult = normalmap_intensity*(1.0-wetness*lmcoord.t*0.65)*atten;

        bump = bump * vec3(bumpmult, bumpmult, bumpmult) + vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f - bumpmult);
        mat3 tbnMatrix = mat3(tangent.x, binormal.x, normal.x,
                                  tangent.y, binormal.y, normal.y,
                                  tangent.z, binormal.z, normal.z);

            frag2 = vec4(normalize(bump * tbnMatrix) * 0.5 + 0.5, 1.0);

    float dirtest = 0.4;

    if (worldTime < 12700 || worldTime > 23250) {
        lightVector = normalize(sunPosition);
    } 

    else {
        lightVector = normalize(moonPosition);
    }

    dirtest = mix(1.0-0.8*step(dot(frag2.xyz*2.0-1.0,lightVector),-0.02),0.4,float(translucent > 0.01));


/* DRAWBUFFERS:0246 */

    gl_FragData[0] = texture2DGradARB(texture, adjustedTexCoord.st, dcdx, dcdy) * color;
    gl_FragData[1] = frag2; 
    gl_FragData[2] = vec4(lmcoord.t, dirtest, lmcoord.s, 1.0);
    gl_FragData[3] = texture2DGradARB(specular, adjustedTexCoord.st, dcdx, dcdy);
}
```

My `gbuffers_terrain.vsh`:

```
#version 120
/*
RRe36's Shaders, derived from Chocapic13 v4
Place two leading Slashes in front of the following '#define' lines in order to disable an option.
IMPORTANT: Placing Slashes in front of lines like '#define FILTER_LEVEL 15.0' will cause errors!
*/

//-------- Adjustable Variables --------//

    //---- Waving Effects ----//
        #define WAVING_LEAVES
        #define WAVING_VINES
        #define WAVING_GRASS
        #define WAVING_WHEAT
        #define WAVING_FLOWERS
        #define WAVING_FIRE
        #define WAVING_LAVA
        #define WAVING_LILYPAD
        #define WAVING_TALLGRASS
        #define WAVING_REEDS

    //---- End of Waving Effects ----//

    //---- Entity IDs ----//
        #define ENTITY_LEAVES        18.0
        #define ENTITY_VINES        106.0
        #define ENTITY_TALLGRASS     31.0
        #define ENTITY_DANDELION     37.0
        #define ENTITY_ROSE          38.0
        #define ENTITY_WHEAT     59.0
        #define ENTITY_LILYPAD      111.0
        #define ENTITY_FIRE          51.0
        #define ENTITY_LAVAFLOWING   10.0
        #define ENTITY_LAVASTILL     11.0
        #define ENTITY_SAPLING     6.0

    //---- End of Entity IDs ----//


    //---- World Effects -----//
        //#define WORLD_CURVATURE                                               // will cause bug at high shadowdistances: looks like a dark circle around you
            const float WORLD_RADIUS         = 6000.0;                      //Increase for a stronger rounded world
            const float WORLD_RADIUS_SQUARED = 15000000.0;

    //---- End of World Effects ----//

//-------- End of Adjustable Variables --------//



const float PI = 3.1415927;

varying vec4 color;
varying vec2 lmcoord;
varying float translucent;
varying vec4 vtexcoordam; // .st for add, .pq for mul
varying vec4 vtexcoord;

varying float dist;

varying vec3 tangent;
varying vec3 normal;
varying vec3 binormal;
varying vec3 viewVector;

attribute vec4 mc_Entity;
attribute vec4 mc_midTexCoord;

uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
uniform mat4 gbufferModelView;
uniform mat4 gbufferModelViewInverse;
uniform int worldTime;
uniform float frameTimeCounter;
uniform float rainStrength;

float timefract = worldTime;

//Calculate Time of Day
float TimeSunrise  = ((clamp(timefract, 23000.0, 24000.0) - 23000.0) / 1000.0) + (1.0 - (clamp(timefract, 0.0, 4000.0)/4000.0));
float TimeNoon     = ((clamp(timefract, 0.0, 4000.0)) / 4000.0) - ((clamp(timefract, 8000.0, 12000.0) - 8000.0) / 4000.0);
float TimeSunset   = ((clamp(timefract, 8000.0, 12000.0) - 8000.0) / 4000.0) - ((clamp(timefract, 12000.0, 12750.0) - 12000.0) / 750.0);
float TimeMidnight = ((clamp(timefract, 12000.0, 12750.0) - 12000.0) / 750.0) - ((clamp(timefract, 23000.0, 24000.0) - 23000.0) / 1000.0);

float animationTime = worldTime/20.0f;

float pi2wt = PI*2*(frameTimeCounter*24 + (rainStrength*2));

vec3 calcWave(in vec3 pos, in float fm, in float mm, in float ma, in float f0, in float f1, in float f2, in float f3, in float f4, in float f5) {
    vec3 ret;
    float magnitude,d0,d1,d2,d3;
    magnitude = sin(pi2wt*fm + pos.x*0.5 + pos.z*0.5 + pos.y*0.5) * mm + ma;
    d0 = sin(pi2wt*f0)*(rainStrength*2);
    d1 = sin(pi2wt*f1)*(rainStrength*1.75);
    d2 = sin(pi2wt*f2)*(rainStrength*1.5);
    ret.x = sin(pi2wt*f3 + d0 + d1 - pos.x + pos.z + pos.y) * magnitude;
    ret.z = sin(pi2wt*f4 + d1 + d2 + pos.x - pos.z + pos.y) * magnitude;
    ret.y = sin(pi2wt*f5 + d2 + d0 + pos.z + pos.y - pos.y) * magnitude;
    return ret;
}

vec3 calcMove(in vec3 pos, in float f0, in float f1, in float f2, in float f3, in float f4, in float f5, in vec3 amp1, in vec3 amp2) {
    vec3 move1 = calcWave(pos      , 0.0027, 0.0400, 0.0400, 0.0127, 0.0089, 0.0114, 0.0063, 0.0224, 0.0015) * amp1;
    vec3 move2 = calcWave(pos+move1, 0.0348, 0.0400, 0.0400, f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5) * amp2;
    return move1+move2;
}

vec3 calcWaterMove(in vec3 pos) {
    float fy = fract(pos.y + 0.001);

    if (fy > 0.002) {
        float wave = 0.05 * sin(2 * PI * (worldTime / 86.0 + pos.x /  7.0 + pos.z / 13.0))
                    + 0.05 * sin(2 * PI * (worldTime / 60.0 + pos.x / 11.0 + pos.z /  5.0));
        return vec3(0, clamp(wave, -fy, 1.0-fy), 0);
    }

    else {
        return vec3(0);
    }
}

//////////////////////////////main//////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////main//////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////main//////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////main//////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////main//////////////////////////////

void main() {
    vec2 texcoord = (gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0).st;
    vec2 midcoord = (gl_TextureMatrix[0] *  mc_midTexCoord).st;
    vec2 texcoordminusmid = texcoord-midcoord;
    vtexcoordam.pq  = abs(texcoordminusmid)*2;
    vtexcoordam.st  = min(texcoord,midcoord-texcoordminusmid);
    vtexcoord.st    = sign(texcoordminusmid)*0.5+0.5;

    translucent = 0.0f;


    float istopv = 0.0;
    if (gl_MultiTexCoord0.t < mc_midTexCoord.t) istopv = 1.0;
    /* un-rotate */
    vec4 position = gbufferModelViewInverse * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    vec3 worldpos = position.xyz + cameraPosition;

    //initialize per-entity waving parameters
    float parm0,parm1,parm2,parm3,parm4,parm5 = rainStrength*4;
    vec3 ampl1,ampl2;
    ampl1 = vec3(0.0);
    ampl2 = vec3(0.0);

#ifdef WAVING_LEAVES
    if (( mc_Entity.x == ENTITY_LEAVES || mc_Entity.x == 161 )) {
            parm0 = 0.0040;
            parm1 = 0.0064;
            parm2 = 0.0043;
            parm3 = 0.0035;
            parm4 = 0.0037;
            parm5 = 0.0041;
            ampl1 = vec3(1.0,0.2,1.0) + rainStrength/4;
            ampl2 = vec3(0.5,0.1,0.5) + rainStrength/4;
            }
#endif

#ifdef WAVING_VINES
    if ( mc_Entity.x == ENTITY_VINES ) {
            parm0 = 0.0040;
            parm1 = 0.0064;
            parm2 = 0.0043;
            parm3 = 0.0035;
            parm4 = 0.0037;
            parm5 = 0.0041;
            ampl1 = vec3(1.0,0.2,1.0);
            ampl2 = vec3(0.5,0.1,0.5);
            }

#endif

#ifdef WAVING_REEDS
    if ( mc_Entity.x == 83 ) {
            parm0 = 0.0024;
            parm1 = 0.0020;
            parm2 = 0.0016;
            parm3 = 0.0010;
            parm4 = 0.0009;
            parm5 = 0.0002;
            ampl1 = vec3(0.25,0.05,0.25) + rainStrength/5;
            ampl2 = vec3(0.125,0.025,0.125) + rainStrength/5;
            }

#endif
        if (istopv > 0.9) {
#ifdef WAVING_GRASS
    if ( mc_Entity.x == ENTITY_TALLGRASS || mc_Entity.x == ENTITY_SAPLING) {
            parm0 = 0.0041;
            parm1 = 0.0070;
            parm2 = 0.0044;
            parm3 = 0.0038;
            parm4 = 0.0063;
            parm5 = 0.0;
            ampl1 = vec3(0.8,0.0,0.8) + 0.2 + rainStrength/3;
            ampl2 = vec3(0.4,0.0,0.4) + 0.2 + rainStrength/3;
            }
#endif

#ifdef WAVING_FLOWERS
    if ((mc_Entity.x == ENTITY_DANDELION || mc_Entity.x == ENTITY_ROSE)) {
            parm0 = 0.0041;
            parm1 = 0.005;
            parm2 = 0.0044;
            parm3 = 0.0038;
            parm4 = 0.0240;
            parm5 = 0.0;
            ampl1 = vec3(0.8,0.0,0.8) + rainStrength/3;
            ampl2 = vec3(0.4,0.0,0.4) + rainStrength/3;
            }
#endif

#ifdef WAVING_WHEAT
    if ( mc_Entity.x == ENTITY_WHEAT  || mc_Entity.x == 141  || mc_Entity.x == 142) {
            parm0 = 0.0041;
            parm1 = 0.0070;
            parm2 = 0.0044;
            parm3 = 0.0240;
            parm4 = 0.0063;
            parm5 = 0.0;
            ampl1 = vec3(0.6,0.0,0.8) + rainStrength/3;
            ampl2 = vec3(0.4,0.0,0.5) + rainStrength/3;
            }
#endif

#ifdef WAVING_FIRE
    if ( mc_Entity.x == ENTITY_FIRE) {
            parm0 = 0.0105;
            parm1 = 0.0096;
            parm2 = 0.0087;
            parm3 = 0.0063;
            parm4 = 0.0097;
            parm5 = 0.0156;
            ampl1 = vec3(1.2,0.4,1.2) + rainStrength*1.8;
            ampl2 = vec3(0.8,0.8,0.8) + rainStrength*1.8;
            }               
#endif
}
    float movemult = 0.0;
#ifdef WAVING_LAVA
    if ( mc_Entity.x == ENTITY_LAVAFLOWING || mc_Entity.x == ENTITY_LAVASTILL ) movemult = 0.25;

#endif

#ifdef WAVING_LILYPAD
    if ( mc_Entity.x == ENTITY_LILYPAD )  movemult = 1.0 + (rainStrength*0.5);
#endif

#ifdef WAVING_TALLGRASS
    if ( mc_Entity.x == 175) {
            parm0 = 0.0031;
            parm1 = 0.004;
            parm2 = 0.0034;
            parm3 = 0.0028;
            parm4 = 0.0163;
            parm5 = 0.0;
            ampl1 = vec3(0.4,0.0,0.4);
            ampl2 = vec3(0.2,0.0,0.2);
            }
#endif


#ifdef WORLD_CURVATURE
if (gl_Color.a != 0.8) {
    float distanceSquared = position.x * position.x + position.z * position.z;
    position.y -= WORLD_RADIUS - sqrt(max(1.0 - distanceSquared / WORLD_RADIUS_SQUARED, 0.0)) * WORLD_RADIUS;
}   
#endif


    position.xyz += calcWaterMove(worldpos.xyz) * movemult;
    position.xyz += calcMove(worldpos.xyz, parm0, parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4, parm5, ampl1, ampl2);

    if ( mc_Entity.x == 37 || mc_Entity.x == 31 || mc_Entity.x == 175 || mc_Entity.x == 59 || mc_Entity.x == 141 || mc_Entity.x == 142 || mc_Entity.x == 31  )

    translucent = 1.0;

    /* re-rotate */

    /* projectify */
    gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gbufferModelView * position;

    color = gl_Color;

    lmcoord = (gl_TextureMatrix[1] * gl_MultiTexCoord1).xy;

    normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);

         tangent = vec3(0.0);
     binormal = vec3(0.0);
     normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);

    if (gl_Normal.x > 0.5) {
        //  1.0,  0.0,  0.0
        tangent  = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vec3( 0.0,  0.0, 1.0));
        binormal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vec3( 0.0, -1.0,  0.0));
    } else if (gl_Normal.x < -0.5) {
        // -1.0,  0.0,  0.0
        tangent  = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vec3( 0.0,  0.0,  1.0));
        binormal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vec3( 0.0, -1.0,  0.0));
    } else if (gl_Normal.y > 0.5) {
        //  0.0,  1.0,  0.0
        tangent  = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vec3( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0));
        binormal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vec3( 0.0,  0.0,  1.0));
    } else if (gl_Normal.y < -0.5) {
        //  0.0, -1.0,  0.0
        tangent  = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vec3( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0));
        binormal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vec3( 0.0,  0.0,  1.0));
    } else if (gl_Normal.z > 0.5) {
        //  0.0,  0.0,  1.0
        tangent  = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vec3( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0));
        binormal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vec3( 0.0, -1.0,  0.0));
    } else if (gl_Normal.z < -0.5) {
        //  0.0,  0.0, -1.0
        tangent  = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vec3( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0));
        binormal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vec3( 0.0, -1.0,  0.0));
    }

mat3 tbnMatrix = mat3(tangent.x, binormal.x, normal.x,
                                  tangent.y, binormal.y, normal.y,
                                  tangent.z, binormal.z, normal.z);


    viewVector = ( gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex).xyz;

    viewVector = normalize(tbnMatrix * viewVector);
    dist = 0.0;
    dist = length(gbufferModelView *gbufferModelViewInverse * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);
}
```

My `composite.fsh`:

```
#version 120

//------------------------------------
//datLax' OnlyWater v2.0
//
//If you have questions, suggestions or bugs you want to report, please comment on my minecraftforum.net thread:
//http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2381727-shader-pack-datlax-onlywater-only-water
//
//This code is free to use,
//but don't forget to give credits! :)
//------------------------------------

uniform sampler2D gcolor;
uniform sampler2D depthtex0;
uniform sampler2D gaux1;

varying vec4 texcoord;

varying vec3 ambient_color;
varying float TimeMidnight;

uniform int worldTime;

uniform mat4 gbufferProjection;
uniform mat4 gbufferProjectionInverse;
uniform mat4 gbufferModelViewInverse;

uniform float near;
uniform float far;
uniform float viewWidth;
uniform float viewHeight;

float ld(float depth) {
    return (2.0 * near) / (far + near - depth * (far - near));
}

vec3 aux = texture2D(gaux1, texcoord.st).rgb;

float land = aux.b;
float torch_lightmap = aux.b;
float sky_lightmap = aux.g;
float landx = 1.0-step(land, 0.01);
float iswater = 0.0;
float pixeldepth = texture2D(depthtex0,texcoord.xy).x;

float pw = 1.0/ viewWidth;
float ph = 1.0/ viewHeight;


float callwaves(vec2 pos) {
    float wsize = 2.9;
    float wspeed = 0.025f;

    float rs0 = abs(sin((worldTime*wspeed/5.0) + (pos.s*wsize) * 20.0)+0.2);
    float rs1 = abs(sin((worldTime*wspeed/7.0) + (pos.t*wsize) * 27.0));
    float rs2 = abs(sin((worldTime*wspeed/2.0) + (pos.t*wsize) * 60.0 - sin(pos.s*wsize) * 13.0)+0.4);
    float rs3 = abs(sin((worldTime*wspeed/1.0) - (pos.s*wsize) * 20.0 + cos(pos.t*wsize) * 83.0)+0.1);

    float wsize2 = 1.7;
    float wspeed2 = 0.017f;

    float rs0a = abs(sin((worldTime*wspeed2/4.0) + (pos.s*wsize2) * 24.0));
    float rs1a = abs(sin((worldTime*wspeed2/11.0) + (pos.t*wsize2) * 77.0 )+0.3);
    float rs2a = abs(sin((worldTime*wspeed2/6.0) + (pos.s*wsize2) * 50.0 - (pos.t*wsize2) * 23.0)+0.12);
    float rs3a = abs(sin((worldTime*wspeed2/14.0) - (pos.t*wsize2) * 4.0 + (pos.s*wsize2) * 98.0));

    float wsize3 = 0.3;
    float wspeed3 = 0.03f;

    float rs0b = abs(sin((worldTime*wspeed3/4.0) + (pos.s*wsize3) * 14.0));
    float rs1b = abs(sin((worldTime*wspeed3/11.0) + (pos.t*wsize3) * 37.0));
    float rs2b = abs(sin((worldTime*wspeed3/6.0) + (pos.t*wsize3) * 47.0 - cos(pos.s*wsize3) * 33.0 + rs0a + rs0b));
    float rs3b = abs(sin((worldTime*wspeed3/14.0) - (pos.s*wsize3) * 13.0 + sin(pos.t*wsize3) * 98.0 + rs0 + rs1));

    float waves = (rs1 * rs0 + rs2 * rs3)/2.0f;
    float waves2 = (rs0a * rs1a + rs2a * rs3a)/2.0f;
    float waves3 = (rs0b + rs1b + rs2b + rs3b)*0.25;


    return (waves + waves2 + waves3)/3.0f;
}

//----------------MAIN------------------

void main() {

    if(aux.g > 0.01 && aux.g < 0.07) {
        iswater = 1.0;
    }

    vec4 fragposition = gbufferProjectionInverse * vec4(texcoord.s * 2.0f - 1.0f, texcoord.t * 2.0f - 1.0f, 2.0f * pixeldepth - 1.0f, 1.0f);
    fragposition /= fragposition.w;

    float dist = length(fragposition.xyz);
    vec4 worldposition = vec4(0.0);
    worldposition = gbufferModelViewInverse * fragposition; 
    vec3 color = texture2D(gcolor, texcoord.st).rgb;
    const float rspread = 0.30f;

    float wave = 0.0;
    if (iswater == 1.0) {
        wave = callwaves(worldposition.xz*0.02)*2.0-1.0;
        wave = wave;

        const float wnormalclamp = 0.05f;

        float rdepth = pixeldepth;
        float waves = wave;
        float wnormal_x1 = texture2D(depthtex0, texcoord.st + vec2(pw, 0.0f)).x - texture2D(depthtex0, texcoord.st).x;
        float wnormal_x2 = texture2D(depthtex0, texcoord.st).x - texture2D(depthtex0, texcoord.st + vec2(-pw, 0.0f)).x;         
        float wnormal_x = 0.0f;

        if(abs(wnormal_x1) > abs(wnormal_x2)){
            wnormal_x = wnormal_x2;
        } else {
            wnormal_x = wnormal_x1;
        }

        wnormal_x /= 1.0f - rdepth;
        wnormal_x = clamp(wnormal_x, -wnormalclamp, wnormalclamp);
        wnormal_x *= rspread;

        float wnormal_y1 = texture2D(depthtex0, texcoord.st + vec2(0.0f, ph)).x - texture2D(depthtex0, texcoord.st).x;
        float wnormal_y2 = texture2D(depthtex0, texcoord.st).x - texture2D(depthtex0, texcoord.st + vec2(0.0f, -ph)).x;     
        float wnormal_y;

        if(abs(wnormal_y1) > abs(wnormal_y2)){
            wnormal_y = wnormal_y2;
        } else {
            wnormal_y = wnormal_y1;
        }   
        wnormal_y /= 1.0f - rdepth;         

        wnormal_y = clamp(wnormal_y, -wnormalclamp, wnormalclamp);

        wnormal_y *= rspread;

        //Calculate distance of objects behind water
        float refractdist = 0.2 * 10.0f;

        //Perform refraction
        float refractamount = 500.1154f*0.35f*refractdist;
        float refractamount2 = 0.0214f*0.05f*refractdist;
        float refractamount3 = 0.214f*0.15f*refractdist;
        float waberration = 0.105;

        vec3 refracted = vec3(0.0f);
        float refractedmask = 0.0;
        float bigWaveRefract = 0.0;
        float bigWaveRefractScale = 0.0;

        vec2 bigRefract = vec2(wnormal_x*bigWaveRefract, wnormal_y*bigWaveRefract);

        vec2 refractcoord_r = texcoord.st;
        vec2 refractcoord_g = texcoord.st;
        vec2 refractcoord_b = texcoord.st;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
            refractcoord_r = texcoord.st * (1.0f + waves*refractamount3) - (waves*refractamount3/2.0f) + vec2( waves*refractamount2 + (-wnormal_x*0.4f) - bigRefract.x,  waves*refractamount2 + (-wnormal_y*0.4f) - bigRefract.y) * (waberration * 2.0f + 1.0f);
            refractcoord_r = refractcoord_r * vec2(1.0f - abs(wnormal_x) * bigWaveRefractScale, 1.0f - abs(wnormal_y) * bigWaveRefractScale) + vec2(abs(wnormal_x) * bigWaveRefractScale * 0.5f, abs(wnormal_y) * bigWaveRefractScale * 0.5f);

            refractcoord_r.s = clamp(refractcoord_r.s, 0.001f, 0.999f);
            refractcoord_r.t = clamp(refractcoord_r.t, 0.001f, 0.999f); 

            if (refractcoord_r.s > 1.0 || refractcoord_r.s < 0.0 || refractcoord_r.t > 1.0 || refractcoord_r.t < 0.0) {
                break;
            }

            refracted.rgb = texture2D(gcolor, refractcoord_r).rgb;

            refractedmask = texture2D(gaux1, refractcoord_r).g;
            if(refractedmask > 0.01 && refractedmask < 0.07) {
                refractedmask = 1.0;
            }else refractedmask = 0.0; 
        }

        color.rgb = mix(color.rgb, refracted.rgb, vec3(refractedmask)); 

    }

    wave = wave*0.5+0.5;
    if (iswater > 0.9){ 
        wave += 0.02;
    }else{ 
        wave = 0.0;
    }

    if (landx == 1.0) {
        //vec3 torchcolor = vec3(1.0, 0.675, 0.415);
        vec3 torchcolor = vec3(0.8, 0.7, 0.3);  
        vec3 torchlight_lightmap = torch_lightmap * torchcolor;

        color = color * torchlight_lightmap * TimeMidnight + color * ambient_color;

    }

    /* DRAWBUFFERS:3 */ 

    gl_FragData[0] = vec4(color, 1.0);


/* DRAWBUFFERS:NNN3N5 */

    gl_FragData[5] = vec4(0.0, wave, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl_FragData[3] = vec4(color, land);
}
```

My `composite.vsh`:

```
#version 120

//------------------------------------
//datLax' OnlyWater v2.0
//
//If you have questions, suggestions or bugs you want to report, please comment on my minecraftforum.net thread:
//http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2381727-shader-pack-datlax-onlywater-only-water
//
//This code is free to use,
//but don't forget to give credits! :)
//------------------------------------

varying vec4 texcoord;

varying float TimeMidnight;
varying float TimeSunset;
varying float TimeNoon;
varying float TimeSunrise;

varying vec3 ambient_color;

uniform int worldTime;

void main() {
    gl_Position = ftransform();

    texcoord = gl_MultiTexCoord0;

    float timefract = float(worldTime);
     TimeSunrise  = ((clamp(timefract, 23000.0, 24000.0) - 23000.0) / 1000.0) + (1.0-(clamp(timefract, 0.0, 6000.0)/6000.0));     
     TimeNoon     = ((clamp(timefract, 0.0, 6000.0)) / 6000.0) - ((clamp(timefract, 6000.0, 12000.0) - 6000.0) / 6000.0);  
     TimeSunset   = ((clamp(timefract, 6000.0, 12000.0) - 6000.0) / 6000.0) - ((clamp(timefract, 12000.0, 12750.0) - 12000.0) / 750.0);   
     TimeMidnight = ((clamp(timefract, 12000.0, 12750.0) - 12000.0) / 750.0) - ((clamp(timefract, 23000.0, 24000.0) - 23000.0) / 1000.0);

    vec3 sunrise_amb;
     sunrise_amb.r = TimeSunrise;
     sunrise_amb.g = TimeSunrise;
     sunrise_amb.b = TimeSunrise;

    vec3 noon_amb;
     noon_amb.r = TimeNoon;
     noon_amb.g = TimeNoon;
     noon_amb.b = TimeNoon;

    vec3 sunset_amb;
     sunset_amb.r = 0.95*TimeSunset;
     sunset_amb.g = 0.95*TimeSunset;
     sunset_amb.b = 0.95*TimeSunset;

    vec3 midnight_amb;
     midnight_amb.r =  0.45*TimeMidnight;
     midnight_amb.g =  0.45*TimeMidnight;
     midnight_amb.b =  0.7*TimeMidnight;

    ambient_color.r = sunrise_amb.r + noon_amb.r + sunset_amb.r + midnight_amb.r;
    ambient_color.g = sunrise_amb.g + noon_amb.g + sunset_amb.g + midnight_amb.g;
    ambient_color.b = sunrise_amb.b + noon_amb.b + sunset_amb.b + midnight_amb.b;
}
```

I am using a 128x128 resource pack, and I don't know much about shaders. Why are faces of grass blocks flickering, and is there a way to fix this? Also, when recording from OBS screen capture, the video turns out flashing. **Reminder:** I pulled `gbuffers_terrain` from a completely different shaderpack.

Specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit
- RAM: 8GB
- CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-4460 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4
- GPU: Intel® Haswell Desktop
- OpenGL:

  ```
  OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
  OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Desktop 
  OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 12.1.0-devel
  OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
  OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
  OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
  OpenGL core profile extensions:
  OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.1.0-devel
  OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
  OpenGL context flags: (none)
  OpenGL extensions:
  OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 12.1.0-devel
  OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
  OpenGL ES profile extensions:
  ```

Comment: @Andreas yes, the (supposed to be) drawn grass block faces flicker.

Comment: Why the [c++] tag ?

Comment: @Quentin SO suggested it, I can remove it if it doesn't fit.

Comment: @moo_we_all_do Well there's no C++ in there at all, so it *is* superfluous. I've removed it and added the GLSL tag :)